# Ubuntu 20.04 won't boot after windows 10 update

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm having an issue booting Ubuntu, it was working perfectly fine since I installed it, but after updating windows 10 yesterday, I can't boot into Ubuntu.

When I select Ubuntu from the screen it just stays blank. I watched a video which said to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then enter and IT WORKED, but it's not permanent. Every time I boot I need to do it and it doesn't always work.

So any help on this matter is greatly appreciated (PS: I've only been using Ubuntu for less than 2 months so I'm still pretty much a noob at it.)

Comment: Check whether fast boot is off.

Answer (score 3):

There is a few things you can try:

- Change the BIOS boot from Legacy support to UEFI
- Deactivate fast boot in UEFI mode in the BIOS

If that doesn't work:

- Boot your computer from a Live USB
- Open a terminal and run the following commands:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install -y boot-repair`

`boot-repair`

Follow the instructions (select 'recommended repair').
When the repair tool finish, you will get a prompt window with a link and instructions for further support.

If any of the above solve the issue, try to create a `boot-repair` disk (USB).

As a last resource, I'd try to reinstall Ubuntu. You may have the option of reinstall the system and keep softaware and main files.

[Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)